# How can I count the number of occurrences of a simple pattern in a string?

Tags: java, string

For this question, a "pair" in a string is defined as a situation where two instances of one character are separated by another character. So in "AxA" the A's make a pair. Pairs can overlap, so "AxAxA" contains three pairs; two for A and one for x.

Further examples:

**countPairs("axa") → 1

countPairs("axax") → 2

countPairs("axbx") → 1**

I was asked how to compute the number of pairs in a given string in an interview yesterday, and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Too bad I've got some work to do :-/. It's quite an interesting question.

Comment: @Helper Method.i did not get you.where you pointing that i was unable to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An O(n) solution would be  to iterate the string (from 0 to `length-2`) and (using `charAt(..)`) to verify whether the current character is equal to the `current+2`. If so, increment a `pairsCount` variable

```
int pairsCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i ++) {
   if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 2)) {
      pairsCount ++;
   }
}
```

Comment: can i have the logic example please.Im stuck with this since morning.

Comment: @Bozho,One clarification,why have you mentioned `str.length() - 3`

Comment: because this is the last character that a pair can _begin_ with

Comment: well, see you are checking for `i+2`. This means that the last value of `i` should be 2 less than the maximum.

Answer (score 3):

The previous awser don't covert the fact that the caracter in the middle (the separator) must be different.

> For this question, a "pair" in a string is defined as a situation where two instances of one character **are separated by another character**. So in "AxA" the A's make a pair. Pairs can overlap, so "AxAxA" contains three pairs; two for A and one for x.

Must this characters be different ? 
Here what I though if it's have to be different...

```
    int trueNbPair =0;
    for (int i=1;i<str.length()-1;i++)
    {
        char prev = str.charAt(i-1);
        char current = str.charAt(i);
        char next = str.charAt(i+1);

        if (prev == next && current!= prev)
        {
            trueNbPair++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: good catch. I assumed AAA is also considered a pair. But it might be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

with recursion:

```
public int countPairs(String str)
{
    if(str.length() < 3)
        return 0;
    if(str.charAt(0) == str.charAt(2) && str.charAt(0) != str.charAt(1))
        return 1 + countPairs(str.substring(1));
    return countPairs(str.substring(1));
}
```